# Get X Y co-ordinates w.r.t image

Tags: image, macos, desktop-application

I am new to mac application programming. I have created a cocoa-based application for MAC OS X. I have dragged a CustomView on my document Window (in Interface Builder). Then on my Custom View I have dragged a Image Well (with my image in it). When I run the application and click anywhere on my image I want to know the X Y co-ordinates w.r.t image. Any sample code will be much appreciated.

Note: I don't want the X Y co-ordinates w.r.t document window.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subclass of NSImageView with an overridden `mouseDown:` or `mouseUp:` method. The event passed to this method will have the click's location in the window, which can be converted to the view's coordinates with NSView's `convertPoint:fromView:`.